# Cannot find name of 'of'' Angular

Tags: angular

I'm running this code mentioned below in Angular 7.3.2, and I'm getting error

> Cannot find name of 'of'

I tried searching about keyword `of` in Angular couldn't find much information, can you please help if you have info about it

```
const nums = of(1, 2, 3);

const squareValues = map((val: number) => val * val);
const squaredNums = squareValues(nums);

squaredNums.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to import it

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```